# JavaScript code works in localhost but not in live site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, localhost

I have a problem with my code working on localhost but not when I upload it to the server.
I am trying to do a sort of one over the other images with a mark on each-when the mark is clicked there is a sort of a zoom effect and you get to the image below.
I have read the posts and solutions of people with similar problems but it doesn't seem to work for me-I have checked that the path is good and all the case sensitive problems that may occur are not present.
I would be really thankful if someone could help me as I am really new to coding.
I tried using FireBug but it didn't help me much.

**My html file**:

```
<div id="zt-container" class="zt-container">
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-1">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag1" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-2" data-zoom="15" data-speed="850" data-delay="100" style="top:85px;left:165px;width:50px; height:30px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-2">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag2" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-3" data-zoom="20" data-speed="850" data-delay="200" style="top:171px;left:194px;width:50px;height:30px;"></div>
                <!--<div class="zt-tag" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-4" data-zoom="2" data-speed="550" data-delay="0" style="top:155px;left:10px;width:150px;height:100px;"></div>-->
                <!--<div class="zt-tag" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-5" data-zoom="15" data-speed="850" data-delay="0" style="top:15px;left:10px;width:90px;height:50px;"></div>-->
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-1" data-zoom="15" data-speed="700" data-delay="0"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-3">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
        <div class="zt-tag zt-tag3" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-4" data-zoom="10" data-speed="550" data-delay="100" style="top:42px;left:287px;width:130px;height:120px; transform: rotate(-6.6342deg);"></div>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-2" data-zoom="10" data-speed="650" data-delay="20"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-4">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
        <div class="zt-tag zt-tag4" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-5" data-zoom="30" data-speed="1050" data-delay="190" style="top:103px;left:184px;width:50px;height:100px; transform: rotate(0deg);"></div>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-3" data-zoom="2" data-speed="550" data-delay="0"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-5">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag5" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-6" data-zoom="8" data-speed="650" data-delay="10" style="top:110px;left:318px;width:60px;height:50px; transform: rotate(0deg);"></div>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-4" data-zoom="15" data-speed="700" data-delay="0"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-6">
                <img class="zt-current" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" height="100%"/>
                <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-5" data-zoom="8" data-speed="650" data-delay="0"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min_.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.zoomtour.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#zt-container').zoomtour();

    </script>
```

**My jquery.easing.1.3.js file**:

```
    jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
        return jQuery.easing.[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
    },
    easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
    },
easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
},
easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
},
easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
},
easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
},
easeInOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
},
easeInQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
},
easeOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
},
easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
    return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
},
easeInQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
},
easeOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
},
easeInOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
},
easeInSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
},
easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
},
easeInOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
},
easeInExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
},
easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
},
easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if (t==0) return b;
    if (t==d) return b+c;
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
    return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
},
easeInCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
},
easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
},
easeInOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
    return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
},
easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
},
easeOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
},
easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
},
easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
},
easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
},
easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
},
easeInBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
},
easeOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
},
easeInOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if (t < d/2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce (x, t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
    return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
}
});
```

**My jquery.zoomtour.js file**:

```
    (function($) {
var tag         = {
        saveInitialData     : function( $tag ) {
            $tag.data({
                width   : $tag.width(),
                height  : $tag.height(),
                left    : $tag.position().left,
                top     : $tag.position().top
            }).addClass( $tag.data('link') );
        },
        rotate              : function( $tag, cache ) {

            // element's center
            var center      = {
                x   : $tag.position().left + $tag.width() / 2,
                y   : $tag.position().top + $tag.height() / 2
            };

            var quadrant    = tag.getElementQuadrant( center, cache );
            // distance from element's center to the quadrants origin
            var dist_element;
            switch( quadrant ) {
                case 1 :
                    dist_element = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( center.x - 0 ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( center.y - 0 ), 2 ) );
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    dist_element = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( center.x - cache.ztdim.x ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( center.y - 0 ), 2 ) );
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    dist_element = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( center.x - 0 ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( center.y - cache.ztdim.y ), 2 ) );
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    dist_element = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( center.x - cache.ztdim.x ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( center.y - cache.ztdim.y ), 2 ) );
                    break;
            }
            var anglefactor = 25;
            var angle   = ( ( cache.dist_center - dist_element ) / cache.dist_center ) * anglefactor;

            switch( quadrant ) {
                case 1 :
                    $tag.data( 'rotate', angle ).transform({'rotate'    : angle + 'deg'});
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    $tag.data( 'rotate', -angle ).transform({'rotate'   : -angle + 'deg'});
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    $tag.data( 'rotate', -angle ).transform({'rotate'   : -angle + 'deg'});
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    $tag.data( 'rotate', angle ).transform({'rotate'    : angle + 'deg'});
                    break;
            }

        },
        getElementQuadrant  : function( c, cache ) {
            if( c.x <= cache.ztdim.x / 2 && c.y <= cache.ztdim.y / 2 )
                return 1;
            else if( c.x > cache.ztdim.x / 2 && c.y <= cache.ztdim.y / 2 )
                return 2;
            else if( c.x <= cache.ztdim.x / 2 && c.y >= cache.ztdim.y / 2 )
                return 3;
            else if( c.x > cache.ztdim.x / 2 && c.y > cache.ztdim.y / 2 )
                return 4;
        }
    },
    viewport    = {
        zoom                : function( $ztcontainer, $tag, cache, settings ) {
            var $ztitem         = $tag.closest('div.zt-item'),
                ztitemid        = $ztitem.data('id'),
                $ztimage        = $ztitem.children('img.zt-current'),

                zoomfactor      = $tag.data('zoom'),
                speedfactor     = $tag.data('speed'),
                imgdelayfactor  = $tag.data('delay'),
                link            = $tag.data('link'),
                dir             = $tag.data('dir'),

                $new_ztitem     = $ztcontainer.find('div.' + link),
                $new_ztitemimage= $new_ztitem.find('img.zt-current'),

                zoomAnimation   = true;

            if( !link ) return false;

            if( zoomfactor === undefined || speedfactor === undefined || imgdelayfactor === undefined || dir === undefined )
                zoomAnimation = false;

            ( dir === 1 ) ?
                viewport.zoomin( $tag, $ztitem, ztitemid, $ztimage, zoomfactor, speedfactor, imgdelayfactor, zoomAnimation, $new_ztitem, $new_ztitemimage, cache, settings ) :
                viewport.zoomout( $tag, $ztitem, ztitemid, $ztimage, zoomfactor, speedfactor, imgdelayfactor, zoomAnimation, $new_ztitem, $new_ztitemimage, cache, settings );
        },
        zoomin              : function( $tag, $ztitem, ztitemid, $ztimage, zoomfactor, speedfactor, imgdelayfactor, zoomAnimation, $new_ztitem, $new_ztitemimage, cache, settings ) {

            var el_l            = $tag.data('left') + $tag.data('width') / 2,
                el_t            = $tag.data('top') + $tag.data('height') / 2;

            $.fn.applyStyle     = ( zoomAnimation ) ? $.fn.animate : $.fn.css;

            $ztimage.applyStyle( {
                width   : cache.ztdim.x * zoomfactor + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y * zoomfactor + 'px',
                left    : - ( ( zoomfactor * ( 2 * el_l ) ) - ( 2 * el_l ) ) / 2 + 'px',
                top     : - ( ( zoomfactor * ( 2 * el_t ) ) - ( 2 * el_t ) ) / 2 + 'px'
            }, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speedfactor } ) );

            // hide all the other tags (for the current item)
            $ztitem.children('div.zt-tag').hide();

            var imgAnimationCss = {
                width   : cache.ztdim.x + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y + 'px',
                left    : '0px',
                top     : '0px',
                opacity : 1
            };
            if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 )
                imgAnimationCss.rotate  = '0deg';

            var newztimg        = $new_ztitemimage.attr('src');

            var tagCss  = {
                position    : 'absolute',
                width       : $tag.data('width'),
                height      : $tag.data('height'),
                left        : $tag.data('left'),
                top         : $tag.data('top')
            };
            if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 )
                tagCss.rotate   = $tag.data('rotate') + 'deg';

            $ztitem.append(
                $('<img src="' + newztimg + '" class="zt-temp"></img>')
                .css( tagCss )
                .delay(imgdelayfactor)
                .applyStyle( imgAnimationCss, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speedfactor, easing : settings.zoominEasing, complete : function() {
                    viewport.zoominCallback( $(this), $new_ztitem, $ztitem, $ztimage, cache );
                } } ) )
            );

            if( !zoomAnimation )
                viewport.zoominCallback( $ztitem.find('img.zt-temp'), $new_ztitem, $ztitem, $ztimage, cache );
        },
        zoominCallback      : function( $zttemp, $new_ztitem, $ztitem, $ztimage, cache ) {
            $(this).remove();

            $new_ztitem
            .show()
            .children('div.zt-tag')
            .show();

            $ztitem.hide();

            $ztimage.css({
                width   : cache.ztdim.x + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y + 'px',
                left    : '0px',
                top     : '0px'
            });

            cache.animTour  = false;
        },
        zoomout             : function( $tag, $ztitem, ztitemid, $ztimage, zoomfactor, speedfactor, imgdelayfactor, zoomAnimation, $new_ztitem, $new_ztitemimage, cache, settings ) {

            var $originalTag    = $new_ztitem.children( 'div.' + ztitemid ),
                o_tag_w         = $originalTag.data('width'),
                o_tag_h         = $originalTag.data('height'),
                o_tag_l         = $originalTag.data('left'),
                o_tag_t         = $originalTag.data('top'),
                o_tag_r         = $originalTag.data('rotate'),

                el_l            = o_tag_l + o_tag_w / 2,
                el_t            = o_tag_t + o_tag_h / 2;

            $.fn.applyStyle     = ( zoomAnimation ) ? $.fn.animate : $.fn.css;

            $new_ztitemimage.css({
                width   : cache.ztdim.x * zoomfactor + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y * zoomfactor + 'px',
                left    : - ( ( zoomfactor * ( 2 * el_l ) ) - ( 2 * el_l ) ) / 2 + 'px',
                top     : - ( ( zoomfactor * ( 2 * el_t ) ) - ( 2 * el_t ) ) / 2 + 'px'
            });

            $ztitem.hide();

            var $new_ztitem_tags = $new_ztitem.children('div.zt-tag');
            $new_ztitem_tags.hide();

            $new_ztitem.show();

            var expandCss   = {
                width   : cache.ztdim.x + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y + 'px',
                left    : '0px',
                top     : '0px',
                opacity : 1
            };
            if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 )
                expandCss.rotate    = '0deg';

            var imgAnimationCss = {
                width   : o_tag_w + 'px',
                height  : o_tag_h + 'px',
                left    : o_tag_l + 'px',
                top     : o_tag_t + 'px',
                opacity : 0
            };
            if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 )
                imgAnimationCss.rotate  = o_tag_r + 'deg';

            $new_ztitem.append(
                $('<img src="' + $ztimage.attr('src') + '" class="zt-temp"></img>')
                .css( expandCss )
            )

            var $zttemp = $new_ztitem.find('img.zt-temp');

            $zttemp.applyStyle( imgAnimationCss, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speedfactor, complete : function() {
                $(this).remove();
            } } ) );

            if( !zoomAnimation )
                $zttemp.remove();

            $new_ztitemimage
            .delay( imgdelayfactor )
            .applyStyle( {
                width   : cache.ztdim.x + 'px',
                height  : cache.ztdim.y + 'px',
                left    : '0px',
                top     : '0px'
            }, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speedfactor, easing : settings.zoomoutEasing, complete : function() {
                viewport.zoomoutCallback( $new_ztitem_tags, cache );
            } } ) );

            if( !zoomAnimation )
                viewport.zoomoutCallback( $new_ztitem_tags, cache );

        },
        zoomoutCallback     : function( $new_ztitem_tags, cache ) {
            $new_ztitem_tags.show();
            cache.animTour  = false;
        }
    },
    methods     = {
        init                : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    rotation        : true, // if true the tags are rotated
                    zoominEasing    : '',   // zoom out animation easing. ex: easeOutBounce , easeOutBack
                    zoomoutEasing   : ''    // zoom out animation easing.
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $ztcontainer        = $(this),
                        // the container's items / images
                        $ztitems            = $ztcontainer.children('div.zt-item'),
                        // large images
                        $ztimages           = $ztitems.children('img.zt-current'),
                        // the tags
                        $zttags             = $ztitems.children('div.zt-tag'),
                        // some values we will need later..
                        cache               = {
                            // container's width & height
                            ztdim       : {
                                x   : $ztcontainer.width(),
                                y   : $ztcontainer.height()
                            },
                            // check if the browser is <= IE8
                            ieLte8      : ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8),
                            // true if currently animating
                            animTour    : false
                        };

                    // add a loading image until all the images are loaded
                    var $loading            = $('<div class="zt-loading"></div>').prependTo( $ztcontainer );

                    // add the class with value "id" to each one of the items. We will need this later to access the items.
                    $ztitems.each( function() {
                        var $ztitem = $(this);
                        $ztitem.addClass( $ztitem.data('id') );
                    });

                    // distance from the container's center to one of its corners
                    // this will be needed to calculate how much we rotate each tag
                    if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 )
                        cache.dist_center       = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( ( cache.ztdim.x / 2 ), 2 ) + Math.pow( ( cache.ztdim.y / 2 ), 2 ) );

                    $zttags.each(function() {
                        var $tag    = $(this);
                        // save each tag's widh height left and top
                        tag.saveInitialData( $tag );
                        // rotate the tags
                        if( settings.rotation && !cache.ieLte8 && !$tag.hasClass('zt-tag-back') )
                            tag.rotate( $tag, cache );
                    }).hide(); // hide the tags

                    // show the first item
                    $ztitems.not(':first').hide();

                    // preload all large images
                    var loaded      = 0,
                        totalImages = $ztimages.length;

                    $ztimages.each( function() {
                        $('<img>').load( function() {
                            ++loaded
                            if( loaded === totalImages ) {
                                // show all large images (just the first will be visible)
                                $ztimages.show();

                                // hide the loading image
                                $loading.hide();

                                // show the tags
                                $zttags.show();

                                // clicking one tag, zooms in / out
                                $zttags.bind('click.zoomtour', function( e ) {
                                    if( cache.animTour ) return false;
                                    cache.animTour  = true;

                                    var $tag            = $(this);
                                    viewport.zoom( $ztcontainer, $tag, cache, settings );
                                });

                                // hide / show tags on mouse hover
                                $ztcontainer.bind('mouseenter.zoomtour', function( e ) {
                                    if( !cache.animTour )
                                        $zttags.show();
                                }).bind('mouseleave.zoomtour', function( e ) {
                                    if( !cache.animTour )
                                        $zttags.hide();
                                });

                            }
                        }).attr( 'src', $(this).attr('src') );
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.zoomtour = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.zoomtour' );
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

**My css**:

```
    .zt-container{
width:451px;
height:350px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
margin:20px auto;
margin-top: 15%;
background:#fff;
border:7px solid #fff;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ddd;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ddd;
box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ddd;
margin-bottom: 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px){
.zt-container{
    margin-bottom: 58px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px){
.zt-container{
    width:301px;
    height:200px;
}
.zt-tag1{
    top:40px !important;
    left:75px !important;
    width:50px !important;
    height:30px !important;
}
.zt-tag2{
    top:85px !important;
    left:104px !important;
    width:50px !important;
    height:30px !important;
}
.zt-tag3{
    top:27px !important;
    left:187px !important;
    width:60px !important;
    height:50px !important;
}
.zt-tag4{
    top:45px !important;
    left:84px !important;
    width:50px !important;
    height:90px !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
.zt-tag5{
    top:75px !important;
    left:100px !important;
    width:60px !important;
    height:50px !important;
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
}
.zt-current{
position:absolute;
display: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 }
img.zt-temp{
position:absolute;
opacity:0;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
 }
.zt-tag{
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
border:2px solid #fff;
background:transparent url(../images/tag.png) repeat top left;
width:50px;
height:37px;
cursor:pointer;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.zt-tag-back{
width:30px;
height:20px;
left:50%;
bottom:0px;
margin-left:-16px;
background:#fff url(../images/back.png) no-repeat center center;
-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
border:1px solid #fff;
border-bottom:none;
}
.zt-loading{
position:absolute;
width:50px;
height:50px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;
opacity:0.8;
z-index:99999;
-moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
background:#fff url(../images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

**Note**: with .zt-current{ display: none;} in localhost everything works. Whten I put it to display: block; it works also but at the beggining it didn't want to work. In the site online with display: block; you can see one of the images but it doesn't solve the JavaScript problem. Anyway, When using the Inspect Element and you hover the mouse over the src of the image you can see it, so the problem is not the path, I think.
I have put it in fiddle and it doesn't work either. You can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/goL6aerm/. In fact, in fiddle I see another thing I don't see on the localhost nor on the site online-we can see all the markers at once on the image and normally we see only the one related with this photo.

Answer (score 1):

Open your console. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

`easing.[jQuery.easing.def]` That's invalid, it should be `easing[jQuery.easing.def]`

Comment: I've changed it to easing[jQuery.easing.def]-it didn't change anything on the site online but it blocked the script in the localhost.

Comment: And what does your console say now? Any other errors?

Comment: It says what you have written SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
return jQuery.easing.[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d); but even with the correct syntax online it doesn't work. Also in css Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/) and in yellow as warning Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’. Error in parsing value for ‘filter’. Declaration dropped. filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);. And in yellow 5 Error in parsing value for ‘transform’. Declaration dropped.
transform: scale(1) translate(579.1500091552734px, NaNpx)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like that. But I can't understand, even so, why it works perfectly when run on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Where you reference your js files try use small cases and make sure the folder is

```
js
```

and not

```
JS
```

then reference them with lowercase like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zoomtour.js"></script>
```

Comment: I reference them in the head of my html. I have changed the folder to js and changed all the references in my html to js/ but it didn't affect the script. It still doesn't do what it is supposed to do.